# Dimension of irreducible representations of finite p-groups

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group.  Is it true that every irreducible representation of $G$ over
an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero ($\mathbb{C}$, for example) must have dimension a power of $p$?

Proof or reference are appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The degrees of the simple complex representations of a group divide the order of the group, so yes. (In fact, they divide the index of the center of the group, which in your case is smaller.)

See, for example, Serre's book for a proof.

Comment: Serre has quite a few books.  Probably you mean *Linear representations of finite groups*?

Comment: Well, Serre's book *on the subject* :)

Comment: In fact, the degrees divide the index of any abelian subgroup (since a p-group is nilpotent so all subgroups are subnormal). Also, as a side note, if all degrees of irreducible complex characters are powers of some prime p, then the group has an abelian normal p-complement, so it behaves almost like a p-group.

Comment: @Mariano & Jiangwe: In fact, it's even better: the square of the degree of each  irreducible character of any finite nilpotent group $G$ divides $[G:Z(G)]$!

Comment: @Geoff: nice. Do you have a reference on that?

Comment: Do you know what page/what chapter of Serre's book it is in?